# How to exclude certain slides from handout

Tags: beamer

I have a made a quite standard beamer (3.12) presentation. To make my long academic presentation a bit more interesting I have inserted some (really, only two or three) slides with "random" pictures like lolcats to keep it a bit humorous.

Now I want these slides to be a surprise, so they should not be visible on the handout. How can I prevent these slides to be included on my `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}` version?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can add `<handout:0>` to the frame you want to hide, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hello.
\end{frame}

% this frame won't be included in the handout mode
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
I am a lolcat!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** As Andrew suggested in the comment, you can use `beamer:0` as well to hide it from the presentation. `:)` Besides, I agree with Andrew, please try to avoid lolcats at all costs, *specially* for academic purposes.

[image: lolcat]

Too risky.

Comment: Even better, if you put `beamer:0` as well then they won't be in the presentation either (The advice of the Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Seminar Audiences is that lolcats should definitely *not* appear in presentations.)

Comment: @Andrew I said 'like' lolcats ;). And actually, my pictures will have still some relation to the content of my actual presentation.

Comment: @Peter: Ah I thought you wanted legit lolcats. My bad. `:P`

Comment: FYI, you can also use `trans`.  This would be useful if, for instance, you wanted to create a limited set of slides for, say, promotional purposes.  Use of `trans` here frees up `handout` to be used for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 16):

To add to the suggestions above, to disable the frame in both handout and beamer modes, one must add

```
<handout:0|beamer:0>
```

Comment: Or simply `<all:0>`.