# Handout is not the same as last displayed state of a frame

Tags: beamer, overlays, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exclude certain slides from handout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35027/how-to-exclude-certain-slides-from-handout)

OK. Here is the MWE that explains it all. When compiled as beamer (onscreen) option, the itemized items appear on every click. Are red colored and bold as they appear. But go back to normal view as soon as the slideshow advances. The final view of the slide is all lines except the 'permanently bold' line are normal.

But when compiled as a handout, the entire itemized list appears red colored and bold.

Is there a way in which handout view = last view of the frame on-screen can be achieved?

```
% this is for onscreen
 \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,english,professionalfonts,smaller]{beamer}
% \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,english,professionalfonts,smaller,handout]{beamer}                                                                               

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=Black]{structure}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Leave the competition behind}

\pause

Some Text that remains normal all through.

\pause

    \begin{itemize}

    \item \alert <.>{\textbf <.> {Want this bold and alert when just displayed}}
    \item \alert <.>{\textbf <.> {But remains bold and alert in handout, too}}
    \item \alert <.>{\textbf <.> {The question is, how to avoid this}}

    \end{itemize}

    \uncover <+-> {Some other text that too remains normal all through}

    \uncover <+-> {\Large{\textbf{Want this bold permanently}}}

    \uncover <+-> {See, earlier text remains bold}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add `handout:0` to the effects that you want to suppress.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35027/86 for another example (for more, search for `handout:0` on this site).

Comment: @AndrewStacey that is possible but cumbersome. Could not there be an easier way?

Comment: At the moment, you are specifying `\alert<.>{something}` and the `<.>` specification says "On the current slide, do this".  In handout mode, that gets activated.  So you need some way to specify "Don't take this action on handouts" and that's the `handout:0` overlay specification.

Comment: Mind you, there could be a possible follow-up question to this (to which I don't know the answer) as to whether or not it is possible to *automatically* include the `handout:0` on *certain* actions.  So `\alert` or `\textbf`, but not on `\uncover`.